# How to get weekly data from table?

Tags: mysql

The start of the week is Tuesday and end of the week is Monday. Could not use week() function since the week starts on Sunday or Monday. 
The table contains daily information and I would like to get weekly summaries of the table. Thanks.

Comment: [How to get record in mysql that has a time in between two dates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14540949/how-to-get-record-in-mysql-that-has-a-time-in-between-two-dates?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could do this:

```
select week(date(datecol - 1)), . . .
. . .
group by week(date(datecol - 1))
```

That is, calculate the week by subtracting one day from the date.

Comment: Thanks Gordon! It would depend on the mode used for the week function.   
For example, use mode 3 would need to minus 1 day, but mode 4 would need to minus 2 days. May also need to use date_sub function.